# Group a List<Object> into List<List<Object>>

Tags: c#, linq, list

How can I `Group` a `List<Person> Persons` by `Person.Age` using `LINQ` and create a new `List<List<Person>> PersonsByAge` ?

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name;
    public int Age
}
```

Comment: Why do you need lists?

Comment: @albertjan Do I have a better alternative here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `GroupBy` and a few `ToList` calls should do the job:

```
List<Person> persons = ...;
List<List<Person>> byAge = persons
                           .GroupBy(p => p.Age)
                           .Select(ps => ps.ToList())
                           .ToList();
```

Comment: Care to explain what doesn't work? It works fine here.

Comment: did you try this in a foreach loop?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would look like this:

```
var persons = new List<Person>
{
    new Person { Age = 20 },
    new Person { Age = 30 },
    new Person { Age = 20 },
    new Person { Age = 40 },
    new Person { Age = 50 },
    new Person { Age = 50 },
    new Person { Age = 20 }
};

var result =    from person in persons
                group person by person.Age into g
                select g.ToList();
var listOfListOfPersons = result.ToList();
```

This would create a `List` holding `List<Person>` items.

Yet another possibility would be to create a class representing the (strongly typed) `List<List<Person>>` structure:

```
public class Persons
{
    public List<Person> Entries { get; set; }
}
public class Person
{
    public Int32 Age { get; set; }
}
```

and fill it like this:

```
var result =    from person in persons
                group person by person.Age into g
                select new Persons
                {
                    Entries = g.ToList()
                };
var listOfListOfPersons = result.ToList();
```

Comment: Ad 1) Why do you need anonymous type to hold just one item?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Fixed it - removed the anonymous object. Thanks.